# Default soft keyboard does not hide in Nexus tab or Virtual Machine

Tags: android, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I'm working on an app where I'm using a custom keyboard for user input in my app. The problem is that the default soft Keyboard does not hide when I run my app on Nexus Tab or Virtual Box Virtual machine. It does not even pop up my custom soft key board on Tab and the VM, however when I run the app on Android Phones It just works fine. I am using following code to hide the default soft key board:

```
public static void hideKeyboard(Context context, View v) {

        try {
            Log.v("hideKeyboard", "Inside hideKeyboard");
            InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            Log.v("hideKeyboard", "InputMethodManager created");
            View view = ((Activity) context).getCurrentFocus();

            if (view != null) {
                Log.v("View found:", "nn");
                inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
                Log.v("HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS:", "nn");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

- I've even searched many similar questions on this forum and even
  tried most of those solutions but that just did not help. Any idea
  why this works on phones and does not work on Nexus Tab and Virtual
  machine????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

call bellow method like 
hideKeyboard(getApplicationContext(),
                editText.getWindowToken()).

```
public void hideKeyboard(Context c, IBinder windowToken) {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) c
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    mgr.hideSoftInputFromWindow(windowToken, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code, this might work, because it's working perfectly with my vm

```
public static void hideKeypad(Activity activity)
{
try
{
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) activity.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    // imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0); //
    // hide
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(activity.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
} catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}
```